# Constraints for Rotor Balancing Problem with CVXPY

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am a machinery engineer with minimum background on math. I was tempted to use CVXPY to write a simple code about rotor balancing problem. It was amazing how simple and robust it works. My problem was as follows:

---

After getting user input for a matrix `ALPHA(M,N)` and `A(M,1)`

```
W=cvxpy.Variable((N,1),complex=True)    
objective2=cvxpy.Minimize(cvxpy.norm((ALPHA*W+A),"inf"))
prob2.solve()
```

---

W is complex, as it returns the weights and its angle for each `N` plane that balance the rotor.

My question is how to put a constraint on `W`. For instance, how to make sure `W` is less than certain value for each `N` plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a user input for constraint masses matrix `wc(N,1)` the following code seemed to do the trick:

```
const=[]
const +=   [cp.norm(W2[i])<=wc[i]for i in range (N) ]
prob3=cp.Problem(objective2,const)
prob3.solve()
```